# Google map with actionBarSherlock - Android studio?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, actionbarsherlock, android-maps-v2, actionbarsherlock-map

I am using from this [LINK](https://github.com/ddewaele/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/tree/master/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock) ,I imported this sample to my android studio 2.1.2 but get me some error.

My gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ecs.google.maps.v2.actionbarsherlock"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 18
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.1'
    compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.15.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.15.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-jackson2-1.15.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')

}
```

And :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Here is my error :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem resolved :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ecs.google.maps.v2.actionbarsherlock"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
    compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.15.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.15.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-jackson2-1.15.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
}
```

And :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```